# Why doesn't svn import work?

Tags: svn, macos, version-control

I have subversion setup on Mac OS X 10.5.6.  When I do

```
svn import myproject file:///library/subversion/myproject/trunk -m "initial import"

Committed revision 2.
```

Nothing happens.  I'm back at the command prompt and no files are imported. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think more details might be necessary

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure about that?  It said [import](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.import) was committed...try a checkout! (and read the [book](http://svnbook.org):)

Comment: Have you read the book?  Notice all of the "Adding..." entries: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.importing.html.  If those aren't there, nothing is added.

Comment: Can we assume there are files actually under /library/subversion/myproject/trunk?  
Either do a svn checkout URL or svn list URL to confirm the directory was added. Also note that svn import is designed to be used without a working copy, but svn add uses a working copy.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the steps I did for the second account, which works fine.  repo, repo2 and testdocs are in the root folder.

Log into usera account
Open Terminal and....

```
MacBook:/ usera$ svnadmin create repo2
MacBook:/ usera$ chmod -R a+rwX repo2
MacBook:/ usera$ cd testdocs
MacBook:testdocs usera$ svn import file:///repo2 -m "initial import"
Adding         questions.rtf
Adding         UsingStatement.txt
Adding         questions2.txt
Adding         iPhone.rtf

Committed revision 1.
MacBook:testdocs usera$
```

Then I opened repo2 in svnX.  All files are there. I log off of usera and logon to my account.  I had already done the above but with "repo".  Those are the results I've already posted, which show import not working.  I open repo2 with svnX.  All files are still there.  I open repo with svnX.  No files.  Why does it work in one account and not in another?

Answer (score 1):

What are you expecting to happen? The the files (if any) in myproject wil be added to the repository. Nothing will be changes in myproject itself - to get a working copy you need to do a checkout.

Comment: I'm expecting to see lines such as "Added..., Addedd...".  Meaning files are actually being add, which they are not.  I created another user account, a new repository added to it.  I got the "Added..." lines and could also see the files in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

for more information see the svn ebook here! 
-> http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You should be importing to:

```
file:///Library/...
```

not

```
file:///library/...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell SVN which files in the current directory you want to add to the repository before you commit.

```
svn add [filename]
```

--Edit

OK Quick Lesson

navigate to the directory you want to be your "Working copy" for your repository.

```
SVN CHECKOUT [my_repository_address]
```

Create the files you wish to add to your repository then add them

```
SVN ADD [my_file]
```

Commit your changes back to the repository

```
SVN COMMIT
```

When you are done please go and read the SVN book which is freely available on-line:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/index.html

Comment: If I try svn add [mydirectory], I get: svn: '.' is not a working copy
svn: Can't open file '.svn/entries': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

User permissions? You may not have access to the repro files.