# How to add files to file based repository?

Tags: svn, version-control

I just downloaded Cornerstone and would like to add my existing files to a new repository.  The repository will be file based (no server) and used by a single developer.  In Cornerstone, I create a repository.  It doesn't have any folders.  I then select one of my existing project folders and import it.  The folder imports but none of my files or subfolders are there.  I've tried this with other folder and get the same results.

I then added the box2d repository from box2d.svn.sourceforge.net using HTTPS.  That added fine and I see its three main folders (branches, tags, trunk). I was able to check it out into a working folder.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.2.  Any ideas why I can't add anything to the repository I created?

-- EDIT --

I tried the following via command line to see if it made any difference:

```
MacBook:sdkiq userA$ svn checkout file:///svnrepository/projectA
svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///svnrepository/projectA'
```

I then went to the svnrepository folder and did:

```
MacBook:svnrepository userA$ svn info
svn: '.' is not a working copy
```

I then created a new repository through the command line, which worked.  I also added a folder to it through Cornerstone, which you can see below:

```
MacBook:developer userA$ svnadmin create "New Repository"
MacBook:developer userA $ svn list --verbose "file:///Developer/New Repository"
  0  ?                    Nov 28 09:26 ./
MacBook:developer userA $ svn list --verbose "file:///Developer/New Repository"
  1 usera              Nov 28 09:32 ./
  1 usera              Nov 28 09:32 projectA/
```

Then I tried the import with no success:

```
MacBook:projects userA$ svn import projectA "file:///Developer/New Repository/projectA" -m "First Import"
```

I can't see any files in the projectA folder.

-- EDIT --

I see what is happening now but have no idea how to fix it.  This is actually an old problem for me and the reason I abandoned svn a while back.  In my main account, the import does not work.  If I log into another account on my Macbook, it does work: [Why doesn't svn import work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642719/why-doesnt-svn-import-work). I just tested it in the other account and it works fine.

Is there any way I can get svn import to work on my main account?  Is it file permissions or something?

-- Solution Found --

"*" was part of my global ignores in this account for some reason.  After removing it, everything is fine.

Comment: From the svn redbook (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re12.html):  `After importing data, note that the original tree is not under version control. To start working, you still need to svn checkout a fresh working copy of the tree.`  Did you try an `svn checkout` or  `svn info` to see if your folders are actually checked in?

Comment: I'd rather not use the command line since that is what I have Cornerstone for.

Comment: Well you needn't necessarily use the command line.  I just wanted you to confirm that the files have actually not been added to the repository despite the `import` command returning success. Try checking out a fresh copy and see if the files are still not present.

Comment: In regards to your last comment, I've updated the OP since it formats better there.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac, You can use SVNx and xcode to maintain subversion. Its easy and GUI based. SVNx is free software.